# Deduction theorem for the modal mu-calculus

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, modal-logic

Does the modal mu-calculus have a deduction theorem?

If yes, how is it stated? Does it have the 'classical' form (i.e. as in classical propositional logic) or is it more involved?

Comment: Well it can’t possibly have the same form as classical propositional logic, as it conservatively extends modal logic, for which the classical form already fails: modal logic only has deduction theorem in the form that $\Gamma,\phi\vdash\psi$ iff there exists $n$ such that $\Gamma\vdash\bigwedge_{i=0}^n\underbrace{\Box\dots\Box}_i\phi\to\psi$ (this is for a single modality; there is an obvious extension to more types of boxes). I think it is plausible that this form of the deduction theorem also holds for the modal $\mu$-calculus if $\phi$ is a sentence (i.e., if all variables inside $\phi$ ...

Comment: ... are bound by $\mu$ or $\nu$ operators), but otherwise it would have to be even more complicated.